# How do I store a string as a typed array?

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to convert a string to a typed array (specifically a Uint8Array) in javascript. I’m trying to store the ASCII values of the characters of the string as individual array elements.

```
var myString = 'foo bar baz " >';
var arr = new Uint8Array(myString);
console.log(arr.length); // Why is this 0?
```

Why is it that the length of the array I create is 0?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Uint8Array Maybe because none of the constructors accept a `string`?

Comment: what about doing var arr = []; arr.push(myString); console.log(arr.length);

Comment: JavaScript strings are Unicode/UTF-16. Unicode is a superset of ASCII. So, you can only store the ASCII values if the characters happen to be in the ASCII range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this link: http://jsperf.com/string-to-uint8array

This is the fastest way to create a `Uint8Array` from a string:

```
var str  = "your string here";
var uint = new Uint8Array(str.length);

for(var i=0, j=str.length; i<j; ++i){
    uint[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
}
```

As pointed out, your error comes from the fact that the constructor does not accept a string argument. Instead, you can allocate an array based on the size of the string, and insert the characters manually.

Answer (score -1):

From [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/br212477(v=vs.94).aspx) you can see that your constructor needs a length or an array for a single parameter.

I would suggest this :

```
var myString = 'foo bar baz " >';
var arr = new Uint8Array(myString.length);
console.log(arr.length);
```

Comment: This doesn't load the array with any data, which was the intent of the original (non-working) code.